# How to append end of every line with the line itself

Tags: sed, awk

This is in `file.txt`:

```
redcar
bluecar
greencar
```

Im looking for ways to make it become:

```
redcar redcar
bluecar bluecar
greencar greencar
```

I've tried many ways using `sed` with no luck

Comment: Actually I don't understand why this question was migrated from stackoverflow. That's definitely a programming question.

Comment: @bmk How is this a programming question? It's about using `sed`/`awk` to manipulate a text file

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: Yes - but what you have to do is to program using the `sed`/`awk` language to achieve the goal. I never would complain if someone asks a question about `sed`/`awk` on unix.stackexchange. But I really don't understand why it has to be migrated. I could also ask why this is a `unix` question. I think `sed` and `awk` are available for other systems, too.

Comment: @bmk I guess technically `sed` and `awk` could be called programming languages, but you're literally just replacing a line with itself twice -- calling that programming is like saying `export` is part of the bash programming language

Comment: @Michael: OK - I have to admit that that's not a very complex programming task (but if you see the answer of ninjalj - it can also be done in a somewhat more complex way). But nevertheless I think the question is more programming than unix (btw.: why is it unix at all?).

Comment: @bmk Well, it's using \*nix tools; what would you consider valid Unix questions if not this?

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: I kind of agree with bmk. I think this shouldn't be migrated either if it appeared originally on _unix_ or on _stackoverflow_, it's relevant for both, OTOH, if it appeared on _programmers_ ...

Comment: @ninjalj Well, you're arguing with the wrong group -- tell that to the SO mods :). My decision is just "should this be closed on UL or left open" -- I think everyone agrees it's fine here

Comment: @Michael: OK - you're right. The discussion is wrong here - it should be discussed on SO. And: No - the question should not be closed here. It's (as ninjalj said) also fine here.

Comment: @bmk I talked with some SO mods; we're going to leave sed/awk-type questions alone in the future. Thanks for bringing it up

Answer (score 12):

Here is a simple solution using paste:

```
paste -d ' ' file.txt file.txt
```

Comment: Interesitng, and surprising!... *Surprising* because it is notably *faster* than `sed -e "s/\(.*\)/\1 \1/"` and `sed -e "s/.*/& &/"` for anything but the smallest files..  I did some time tests, and although is takes approximately the same time for a file with **1** line, `paste` becomes relatively *much faster* as the number of lines increases..  upt to a whopping **28** times faster with 1,000,000 lines... Here is a lin to the test snippet: http://paste.ubuntu.com/606010/

Comment: @fred That's not so surprising. A specialized tool such as `paste` has optimized code for its particular task, unlike `sed` or `awk` which are interpreters. The penalty you pay is that a specialized tool can only do one job.

Answer (score 11):

Try:

```
sed 's/\(.*\)/\1 \1/' data.txt
```

Comment: You can also use `\0` to match the entire expression, so `s/.*/\0 \0/`

Comment: or `&` (also entire matched part)

Comment: @Michael: You can? Oh, it's a GNU extension. Not in POSIX or OpenBSD. Rather pointless extension since there's `&`.

Comment: General info.. For larger file sizes, this `\1 \1` method is up to 30 times slower than Hai Vu's `paste` method.. and it is also slower than `& &`... Here is a link to my test script:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/606010/

Answer (score 7):

There Is More Than One Way To Do It:

Substitute two times the full sentence:

```
sed 's/.*/& &/'
```

Copy to hold space, append hold space to pattern space, fix newline:

```
sed 'h;G;s/\n/ /'
```

awk, concatenate whole sentence using field separator:

```
awk '$0=$0FS$0'
```

Comment: I've done some time tests: http://paste.ubuntu.com/606010/ ... For large files, `sed -e "h;G;s/\n/ /"` is marginally faster than `sed -e "s/.*/& &/"`, which is marginally faster than `awk '$0=$0FS$0'`, but they are all approx 10 times slower than `paste -d ' ' file file` (as suggested by `Hai Vu` .. I am quite surprised, but that's what the times show...

Answer (score 4):

I would do it in perl but since you put awk, I will give you awk code

```
awk '{print $0,$0;}' file.txt
```

Edit: remove my useless cat